# Elastic search boosting with function_score in nested properties

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch, given the following document structure:

```
"workhistory": {
  "positions": [{
    "company": "Some company",
    "position": "Some Job Title",
    "start": 1356998400,
    "end": 34546576576,
    "description": "",
    "source": [
       "some source", 
       "some other source"
    ]
  },
  {
    "company": "Some other company",
    "position": "Job Title",
    "start": 1356998400,
    "end": "",
    "description": "",
    "source": [
       "some other source"
    ]
  }]
}
```

and mappings for this structure:

```
  workhistory: {
    properties: {    
      positions: {
        type: "nested", 
        include_in_parent: true, 
        properties: {                 
          company: {
            type: "multi_field",
            fields: {
              company: {type: "string"},
              original: {type : "string", analyzer : "string_lowercase"} 
            }              
          }, 
          position: {
            type: "multi_field",
            fields: {
              position: {type: "string"},
              original: {type : "string", analyzer : "string_lowercase"} 
            }              
          }                                                       
        }
      }        
    }
  }
```

I want to be able to search on "company" and match the document if company = "some company" etc. Then I want to to get the tf idf _score. I also want to create a function_score query to boost the score of this match, based on the values of the "source" field array. Basically, if the source contains "some source", boost _score with x amount. I can change the structure of the "source" property if needed.

This is what I got so far:

```
{
   "bool": {
      "should": [
         {
            "filtered": {
               "query": {
                  "bool": {
                     "should": [
                        {
                           "bool": {
                              "should": [
                                 {
                                    "match": {
                                       "workhistory.positions.company.original": "some company"
                                    }
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     ],
                     "minimum_should_match": "100%"
                  }
               },
               "filter": {
                  "and": [
                     {
                        "bool": {
                           "should": [
                              {
                                 "term": {
                                    "workhistory.positions.company.original": "some company"
                                 }
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "function_score": {
               "query": {
                  "bool": {
                     "should": [
                        {
                           "bool": {
                              "should": [
                                 {
                                    "match": {
                                       "workhistory.positions.company.original": "some company"
                                    }
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     ],
                     "minimum_should_match": "100%"
                  }
               },
               "filter": {
                  "and": [
                     {
                        "bool": {
                           "should": [
                              {
                                 "term": {
                                    "workhistory.positions.company.original": "some company"
                                 }
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

There are some filters in here as well, cause I only want to return documents with the filtered value. In this example the filters and the query are basically the same, but in a bigger version of this query I have a few other "optional" matches to boost optional values etc. The function_score is not doing much right now, since I cant really figure out how to work with it. The goal is to be able to adjust the number of the boost in my application code and pass it in to the search query.

I'm using Elasticsearch version 1.3.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you repeated all those filters and queries in there, to be honest. Maybe I'm missing something, but by your description I believe all you need is a "function_score". From the [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html):

> The function_score allows you to modify the score of documents that are retrieved by a query.

So, you define a query (for example - matching the company name) and then define a list of functions that should boost the _score for a certain sub-set of documents. From the same documentation:

> Furthermore, several functions can be combined. In this case one can optionally choose to apply the function only if a document matches a given filter

So, you have the query that looks for companies with a certain name, then you have a filter for a function to manipulate the _score for the documents that match the filter. And your filter, in this case, is the "source" that should contain something. The function itself is a script: `_score + 2`.
In the end, this would be my idea:

```
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "function_score": {
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "should": [
                      {
                        "bool": {
                          "should": [
                            {
                              "match": {
                                "workhistory.positions.company.original": "some company"
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    ],
                    "minimum_should_match": "100%"
                  }
                },
                "functions": [
                  {
                    "filter": {
                      "nested": {
                        "path": "workhistory.positions",
                        "query": {
                          "bool": {
                            "should": [
                              {
                                "match": {
                                  "workhistory.positions.source": "some source"
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "script_score": {
                  "script": "_score + 2"
                }
              },
              {
                "filter": {
                  "nested": {
                    "path": "workhistory.positions",
                    "query": {
                      "bool": {
                        "should": [
                          {
                            "match": {
                              "workhistory.positions.source": "xxx"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                "script_score": {
                  "script": "_score + 4"
                }
              }
            ],
            "max_boost": 5,
            "score_mode": "sum",
            "boost_mode": "sum"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be working, I switched out the script to be a script file in the scripts folder to not have to enable dynamic scripting. I'm almost there, but I need to first score on the regular query, then apply this query to boost the score with my function_score query. So that results will first get sorted on matches in the document, then boosted by this function.

Comment: I also don't know how to apply a different boost if the source is named something else, or not present at all. Will this match on the same nested element, or just any element in that array?

Comment: A different boost for another "source" value is simple: you just define another set of `{ "filter": {}, "script_score" :{} }`. I updated my answer.

Comment: ... aaand I don't understand this statement "I need to first score on the regular query, then apply this query to boost the score with my function_score query. So that results will first get sorted on matches in the document, then boosted by this function."

Comment: I see, great! Lets say I have 10 different sources, I then write one function for each? Will this impact performance a lot? Also, will these sources be matched against the same element in the nested collection/array as the actual query, or just any hit in that collection?

Comment: To clarify the statement you didn't understand: Maybe I misunderstand function_score queries, but as I understand them, the only score that is applied is the one that I define. I want to be able to first calculate the score the "normal" way when doing a match, then only boost that normal score with my own calculations via the function_score query.

Comment: One function for each source you need a different boosting for. Regarding performance, you need to test it, each environment is different and everyone understands "performance" in a different way. Some queries that have good performances for me might not be considered performance worthy by you. The functions will be applied to the documents returned by the initial query.

Comment: Regarding boosting, there are several types: [the documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) lists all of them and in my suggestion I used "sum" which means that the boosting value will be added to the original _score. But you can also "replace" it entirely with your own score.